# Print FastReport directly

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I'm using FastReport in Delphi Win32.

When a FastReport is called, it is previewed before you can print it.

The user sometimes needs to print a series of reports. It's a PITA to preview then print each one separately.

How can I queue the reports and send them directly to the default printer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call PrepareReport followed by Print.  You don't have to show the preview.

```
frxReport1.PrepareReport;
frxReport1.Print;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's written in developper help file (Programmer Manual) Chapter "Building a composite report (batch printing)"

```
frxReport1.LoadFromFile('1.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport;
frxReport1.LoadFromFile('2.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport(False);
frxReport1.Print;
```